# htaccess routing codeigniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, routes

I have a problem with my routes. I have my images in sources/ folder but when the image is missing it cause to load the website and future problem with system overloading.

Htaccess:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|sources|uploads|captcha|sitemap\.xml|_gapi|robots\.txt|googleaac809c6bcbeb4e8\.html|googlebaf6b56ae3013092\.html|feeds|temp)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L,QSA]
```

This should cause to load files from those folders - working well by this point

But when there is image missing for example:

`<img src="uploads/non_existing_image.jpg">` the image wont load but when I copy the URL the website will load correctly and after some time my server ends up with 500 Error.

Is there any way how to solve this in htaccess/php ?

I want to end up with 404 error on that link

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `.htaccess` for this, just Add the index.html file to your images folder also add the index.html in CSS and JavaScript folder. When someone try load you folder `index.html` is auto load and didn't allow your images etc.

**It will give result like this**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i also use a htaccess file with codeigniter, even though mine is quite smaller then yours:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

to explain: `RewriteEngine On` enables the rewriting of the url,
the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` tells htaccess that the requested file should not be an existing file,
the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d` tells htaccess that the requested file should not be an existing directory.

this way you dont need to exclude all the seperate files and/or extentions and/or directories.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* index.php/$0 [PT,L]
```

Just add this to your .htaccess file